# How can I download a **standalone** setup version of Live Messenger to install in other PC?

Tags: download, windows-live-messenger

I want to download the full setup, not the WLSetup where the real bytes are downloaded later.
It is for installing on other PC with bad Internet.

**Is there a way to get it from Microsoft?** I don't trust those rapidShare links.

Comment: A roundabout solution, but do you really need WLM? Couldn't a different client such as Pidgin, Miranda-IM, or Trillian do the job better?

Comment: No, unless you wanna come down to Argentina to give some free classes how to use it to my teenager nephew :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At [download.live.com](http://download.live.com/), when you click on 'Download' button, you are provided with web installer (wlsetup-web.exe).

Cancel it, and you are on page which has a 'Try Again' button.
Clicking this will give you standalone installer for your computer.

Comment: You are right! "Trying again downloads a standalone installer to your computer. This takes a little while, but may work better, depending on your connection settings."

Answer (score 3):

**use the following trick to get the “Messenger.msi” file.**

1. Download Windows Live Installer from download.live.com.
2. Install or upgrade the Windows Live Messenger to latest version.
3. Open Windows Explorer, and set it to Show hidden files and folders and show protected operating system files (uncheck the tick for Hide protected operating system files) in the View tab of Folder Options.

   In Windows Vista, run Windows Explorer as Administrator, and user may requires to take ownership and gain full control permissions for the folders below before able to access them.
4. Browse to \Program Files\Common Files\Windows Live.cache\ folder.
5. There will be a lot of folders made up of 15 characters and numbers. Locate Messenger.msi file inside one of the folder. Messenger.msi is the individual separate standalone setup installer for Windows Live Messenger 2009, which can be backed up or copied to another location. Do note that the Messenger.msi and other Windows Installer Package retrieved this way is silent installer.

   Tip: %ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Windows Live.cache\cache.ini file contains the paths of all Windows Live software products downloaded or installed on the computer.
6. If you have any problem with Windows Live Messenger after installation using the standalone individual installer Messenger.msi, try to install the following 3 programs too, all of which in different sub-folders inside the .cache directory.

   Contacts.msi (Contacts)
     dw20shared.msi (DW 2.0 Client)
     crt.msi (Microsoft Visual Studio Runtime)

   Tip: Contacts.msi is a must to avoid or fix 8000FFFF error.

After grabbing the Windows Live Messenger standalone silent installer, optionally user can uninstall the Windows Live Suite (all programs) from Control Panel, and install Messenger.msi (and Contacts.msi too) again to get rid of all other Windows Live components except WLM9, saving time and bandwidth in future installation.

[source](http://forums.techarena.in/tips-tweaks/1058717.htm)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, but I don't want to go to the whole process. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

TRY HERE http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Chat/Instant-Messaging/Windows-Live-Messenger-9.shtml

Comment: Thanks. It sucks that you have to download it from another company...